# linq to dataset equivalent of SQL LIKE clause

Tags: c#, linq

What is the linq equivalent of a SQL clause like `WHERE UserName LIKE 'fr_d'`?

I'm working with a dataset in memory rather than a SQL database so I don't think I can use something like `where SqlMethods.Like(p.UserName, "Fr_d")`

(Not that my installation of VS2008 is admitting that SqlMethods or even System.Data.Linq.SqlClient
exist at the moment, but thats a whole different problem!)

Comment: It depends on what the contents of the column named fr_d is.

Comment: Did you mean to put `LIKE 'fr_d'` instead of `LIKE fr_d`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
table.Where(row => row.StringColumn.StartsWith("prefix"))
```

(You may also want to call `Contains` or `EndsWith`)

**EDIT**: In your case, you want

```
table.Where(p => p.UserName.StartsWith("Fr") && p.UserName.EndsWith("d") && p.UserName.Length == 4)
```

Alternatively, you can also put a regex inside the `Where` clause.
If you do, make sure to create the `RegEx` object outside the `Where` call so that it doesn't get parsed for each row.

Comment: Notice that he is using a special character with his `LIKE` (assuming he meant to use 'fr_d' instead of fr_d)

Comment: Your second example would select records where UserName is "Fraaaaad" which is not what the corresponding SQL query would do.

Comment: Thanks - I think regex will be the way to go as I need to check for single character differences in any position.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what you really want.  It will allow Fr{*any one character*}d:

```
table.Where(p => p.UserName.StartsWith("Fr") && p.UserName.EndsWith("d") && p.UserName.Length == 4 )
```

Unfortunately I can't find anything that does something similar to SQL's like clause for LINQ to Dataset...

**UPDATE:** Found a similar posting here: [LINQ vs. DataTable.Select - How can I get the same results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849073/linq-vs-datatable-select-how-can-i-get-the-same-results)

They suggest using [i4o](http://i4o.codeplex.com/) which I am not familiar with, but it may be worth investigating (the asker of that question accepted i4o as the answer).